# Prop in a React component being mutated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a weird scenario in which a prop in a React component is being mutated. It's an array, so it's not technically a mutation (in JavaScript land), but still there is no way it should be modified.

I've made a barebones example to replicate the problem. 
http://codepen.io/HoraceShmorace/pen/LRXWWb?editors=0011.

This component:

1. accepts a prop containing initial "group" data,
2. allows you to filter that group data (via a text box),
3. sets a state property to the filtered group data,
4. and then displays the initial prop data and filtered state data side-by-side.

The group data is a list of groups, each with a name and an array of children objects. These children objects will either represent people `{name:[value]}`, or more groups, forming a hierarchy.

The filtering of the group data happens correctly. However, for some reason both the state AND the prop is updated.

Here's the JS:

```
/**
 * Define the component.
 */
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const {initialGroups} = this.props

    //Initialize filtered groups with the intial groups
    this.state = {
      filteredGroups: initialGroups
    }
  }

  /**
   * Simply outputs the props and the state to the screen,
   * as well as an input field that filters the group data.
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Filter by name" onChange={onChange.bind(this)} />
        <section id="output">
          <pre>
            <h1>props:</h1>
            {JSON.stringify(this.props,null,2)}
          </pre>
          <pre>
            <h1>state:</h1>
            {JSON.stringify(this.state,null,2)}
          </pre>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

TestComponent.propTypes = {
  initialGroups: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

/**
 * Define event handler for text input change, 
 * which filters group data recursively,
 * the result of which gets saved in state.
 */
function onChange(e) {
  //Get input value
  const filterInputValue = e.target.value

  //Get initial group data to filter. Note how this is copying the array, non-mutatingly, just in case.
  const initialGroups = [...this.props.initialGroups] 

  //Filter the group data (function defined below).
  const filteredGroups = filterGroupsByPerson(initialGroups) 

  //Update the state
  this.setState({filteredGroups})

  //Recursive filtering function
  function filterGroupsByPerson(arr) {
    return arr.filter(item=>{
      const hasChildren = item.children instanceof Array && item.children.length > 0

      //Having children implies this is a group. Don't test the name, just try to filter the children.
      if(hasChildren) {
        //Filter children array recursively
        item.children = filterGroupsByPerson(item.children) 
        return item.children.length > 0
      }

      //This is a person, not a group. Filter on the name.
      const filterRegex = new RegExp(filterInputValue, 'i')
      const filterResults = filterRegex.test(item.name)
      return filterResults
    })
  }
}

/**
 * Mock up the initial group data
 */
const InitialGroups = [
  {
    "name": "Engineering",
    "children": [
      {"name": "Gates"},
      {"name": "Allen"},
      {"name": "Jobs"},
      {"name": "Wozniak"},
      {
        "name": "Consultants",
        "children": [
          {"name": "Jess"},
          {"name": "Cece"},
          {"name": "Winston"},
          {"name": "Schmidt"}
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]

/**
 * Implement component, passing initial group data as a prop.
 */
ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent initialGroups={InitialGroups}/>, document.getElementById('test-component'))
```

And a little bit of HTML:

```
<div id="test-component"></div>
```

... and CSS:

```
#output {
  display:flex;
}

#output pre {
  background-color: #eeeecc;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `[...this.props.initialGroups]` only performs a **shallow** copy. The objects inside the array are not copied, so `item.children = filterGroupsByPerson(item.children)` is the reason for the effect you see. In other words: Props and state both seem to update because they refer to the same object. Seems like you want to perform a deep copy.

Comment: Why not? ......

Comment: Are you saying the items inside the new array are references to the same items in the old array?

Comment: Yes. If you have `var foo = [{x: 42}];` and `var bar = [...foo];` then `foo[0] === bar[0]` is `true`. Changing `bar[0].x` will affect `foo` since `foo[0]` and `bar[0]` reference the same object.

Comment: Disregard. I get it. Thanks, that was hours of wracking my brain right there. The most elegant solution for deep cloning I could find is `const initialGroups = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.initialGroups))`.

Comment: Add it as an answer, if you want the rep points ;)

Comment: That's not particularly elegant, really, and relies on string parsing; why not use any of the existing `clone` implementations (lodash, whatever)?

Comment: I didn't say it was elegant, but merely the most elegant :D Lodash is too heavy just for this one need, but you're right, I'll use a single-purpose npm module for this.

Comment: This article helped me a lot. https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#replacing-items-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
const filterInputValue = e.target.value
  const intialGroupClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.initialGroups))

  const filteredGroups = filterGroupsByPerson(intialGroupClone) 

  //Update the state
  this.setState({filteredGroups})
```

working pen here http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/YGRxoa